# Google Cloud functions Python Flask templates folder

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying out the Python runtime. I understand that it's using Flask.

I'm using templates in my function but 
1. I don't see the `templates` folder in the uploaded source.
2. `render_template` throws a `TemplateNotFound` error

Actually it doesn't seem to be uploading any folders. Is this a bug or can I do anything about this?

Comment: I assume you were developing the function in local, by your description. The thing is that [you can't upload templates](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy) to use in Functions. This kind of code is more suited for App Engine Standard.

Comment: Actually, turns out that it was uploading the templates folder. It was just not showing in the source tab and I got it working defining the jinga env and rending it inside the function. WITHOUT using flask

Comment: Sounds interesting! Would you mind posting what you did, code and so on, as an answer! Python on GCF is extremely new, so, your contribution to the community on this topic sounds interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the templates folder is getting uploaded but it doesn't show in the source tab.

And I got the templates rendering working by using jinja2 directly instead of using Flask's `render_template`

Solution:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, select_autoescape

context_data = {
    'var1': 'val1',
    'var2': 'val2',
}

env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)

template = env.get_template('template.html')
html = template.render(**context_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

This article details how to do it with Flask:

https://dev.to/googlecloud/html-templates-with-google-cloud-functions-29bc

Structure things as such -- and it magically works.

```
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    └── hello.html
```